# Hackerrank -- Time taken for two squares to overlap

Tags: math

**Problem statement**: [Sherlock and Moving Tiles](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-moving-tiles)

**TL;DR**: Given **2** *squares*; with sides of *length L*, placed in an x-y plane, and both squares **move** along the line **y=x** (along the positive x and y) with velocities *S1* and *S2*, what is the **time taken** at which the **overlapping area** of the two squares is equal to *qi*?

Hey, everyone.

**Context**: I am currently working on my Math skills after having taken some extensive time away from it. I think that it could improve the way I approach coding problems as well by recognising when a problem is Math-related. I'm going through *Hackerrank* & *KhanAcademy* for learning purposes at the moment.

**Question**: I am having trouble **visualising** the formula for the given problem. I have the answer and have also taken a peek at the *editorial*'s answer but I still can't fully grasp it. Perhaps, I am forgetting something fundamental in my math knowledge. The problem's difficulty level is set as **easy**. So, I am a little embarrassed since I am having trouble solving a *relatively* easy Math problem. I hope that you won't hold that against me. :)

Anyway, the **formula** used to solve this problem is as follows:-

```
t = Math.sqrt(2) * (L - Math.sqrt(qi)) / Math.abs(S2-S1)
```

**Could I get a breakdown/upwards derivation of the final formula?** i.e. What do I need to think about in order to arrive at that formula? I understand parts of it but can't seem to pull them together into a conclusive answer.

Thanks for the help, guys. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow the original definition is, apparently, TL;DR. What are their original positions? What are their orientations? From the formula it looks as if they are next to each other.

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah -- Haha. Yeah. The TL;DR was unnecessary, I guess. (0,0) would be their starting positions (t is also at 0). Both squares are moving in such a way that the y-axis is equal to the x-axis. Their orientations are stated in the problem statement as well; "...the left bottom of each square coincides with the the origin and their sides are parallel to the axes.". The picture (in the problem) shows exactly how the squares look like when the overlapping happens + their direction of movement. Hope I've made sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area `qi` is half of the square of the diagonal of the square formed by the intersection of the two squares. We will only look at diagonals here because the squares are moving along `y=x`. We will therefore consider the top right corner of the square with the slower velocity (we do not need to check for this, this will be covered by using the absolute value of the denominator) which we'll call `A` and the bottom left corner of the faster square which we'll call `B`.

The distance `x1` of `A` from the origin is `d1 = s1*t + L*sqrt(2)`.

The distance `x2` of `B` from the origin is `d2 = s2*t`.

We know that `qi = [(x1 - x2)^2] / 2`.

Substituting `x1` and `x2`,
`(s1*t + L*sqrt(2) - s2*t)^2 = 2*qi`.

On taking `sqrt` on both sides and solving for `t`, we end up with:

```
t = sqrt(2) * (sqrt(qi) - L) / (s1 - s2)
```

To make sure that both numerator and denominator are positive, take `-1` common from both the numerator and denominator.

```
t = sqrt(2) * (L - sqrt(qi)) / (s2 - s1)
```

The assumption we have made here is that `s1 < s2`. To make this work for all cases, simply take the absolute value of their difference in the denominator.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for responding. Got a couple more questions.

(1) For **d1**, where does **L*sqrt(2)** come from?

(2) For **qi**, I understand **(x1 - x2)^2** but why is it **divided by 2**?

(3) You mentioned "..taking sqrt on both sides". Could you elaborate more on that? 

Thanks!

Comment: (1) the `L*sqrt(2)` is the distance between the bottom left and top right corner of the slower square. (2) The divide by 2 comes from the formula for area of a square (the intersection area is also a square) `diag^2/2`. (3) By taking sqrt on both sides the equation becomes `t*(s1-s2) + L*sqrt(2) = sqrt(2*qi)`. Solve for `t`.

Comment: Awesome! I understand now. Managed to arrive to the formula thanks to your explanation. Thanks!